# using numpy_where on a 1D array

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing, location

I am trying to use numpy_where to find the index of a particular value. Though I have searched quite a bit on the web including stackoverflow I did not find a simple 1D example.

```
ar=[3,1,4,8,2,1,0]
>>> np.where(ar==8)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

I expected np.where(ar==8) to return me the index/location of 8 in the the array.
What am I doing wrong? Is it something in my array?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a really good example of how the range of variable types in Python and `numpy` can be confusing for a beginner.  What's happening is `[3,1,4,8,2,1,0]` returns a list, not an `ndarray`.  So, the expression `ar == 8` returns a scalar `False`, because all comparisons between list and scalar types return `False`.  Thus, `np.where(False)` returns an empty array.  The way to fix this is:

```
arr = np.array([3,1,4,8,2,1,0])
np.where(arr == 8)
```

This returns `(array([3]),)`.  There's opportunity for further confusion, because `where` returns a tuple.  If you write a script that intends to access the index position (3, in this case), you need `np.where(arr == 8)[0]` to pull the first (and only) result out of the tuple. To actually get the value 3, you need `np.where(arr == 8)[0][0]` (although this will raise an `IndexError` if there are no 8's in the array).

This is an example where numeric-specialized languages like Matlab or Octave are simpler to use for newbies, because the language is less general and so has fewer return types to understand.